# Oracle Apex Force Upper Case first Letter.

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I Guys

In forms I use,

```
onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
```

To force upper-case. However for such as name fields. How do you force the upper letter to be upper-case only while the user is typing. I know INITCAP will do that but need to do as user is typing, if that makes sense.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript question then, not and Oracle or APEX question. It shouldn't make any difference what the environment is as long as you have access to the DOM events with javascript functions. e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

If you do a search there are lots of examples to Initcap a string in javascript, just pass in the string and reset the item in the dom e.g.

```
function capitalizeEachWord(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem.
For that I created JavaScript function which check first letter capital ,if not then it display alert and revert text.
please check following code for text item:

```
function checkUpper()
{
var x = $x("P6_TEXT");
if (x.value.trim().substring(0,1) != x.value.trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase()) {
    alert ('First letter Must be in upper case');
x.value = x.value.trim().substring(0,x.value.trim().length-1).toString();
}
}
```

And set item P6_TEXT attribute as

```
onKeyUp="checkUpper();"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the field custom attributes put this JS code:

onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+this.value.substring(1).toLowerCase();"

Answer (score 0):

You could use content modifiers from Universal Theme https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/content-modifiers
I needed text in a page item to be uppercase and under **Advanced** I set the css classe to
u-textUpper
u-textInitCap - Sets The First Letter In Each Word To Use Uppercase